# 404 problems, staging only

Tags: error, 404, 404-page

I've got a bizarre issue that is only happening on staging. Locally all urls work correctly.

on staging http://domain.com/archives and http://domain.com/photography/entry_slug both return a 404 page generated by the host see screenshot
[image]

However if I actually try to visit a page that truly does not exist the craft 404 page shows, which is what I would expect for a real 404 error. For example http://domain.com/foo

[image]

This is only my second craft site and I have no idea how to troubleshoot. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `/archives` supposed to redirect to `/calendar`?  My guess is there is some `.htaccess` rewrite rule interfering somewhere.

Comment: @BradBell actually the link is to /calendar I just typed it wrong... there is no redirect going on anywhere. I"m also using the vanilla htaccess that comes with Craft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your paths are not set up right; or the SERVER_NAME isn't what you think it is, so it's not matching the paths in your `general.php`

Comment: @khalwhat I double checked and it's the same. Even used this and copied/pasted to be sure $path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 echo $path; - no change still not working as expected.

Comment: So a little more looking and I found a typo in the baseUrl for staging in general.php

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your screenshots, the host names are different.  The cPanel 404 shows mysphotos instead of myphotos.

Probably a typo somewhere in your templates.

Comment: That's true and odd because the link to that page does not have a typo. Not sure what is causign this redirect. Thanks for pointing that out to me. NOw i have somethign to work with.